# True or false: for all $x$ there is a $y$ such that if $x$ is non negative then $y^2 = x$

Tags: predicate-logic, real-numbers

> For all $x$ there is a $y$ such that if $x$ is non negative then $y^2 = x$

Is my logic correct in proving that statement is true ? Can provide an explanation of how to test this proof ?

$x=2$ then $y^2 = 2$
$x=2$ then $y = \sqrt 2$

Truth table for this scenario
$t , t$

This proves there is $y$ such that $y^2 = x$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove the statement by using only one value $x = 2$ to show that for *that* particular value $x$, there exists a $y$ such that $y^2 = x$.

Why not?

You can't stop at showing it's true for one $x$, or two $x$, or even a million values of $x$, because the statement is a claim about *all* $x\geq 0$. Proving a "for all" statement requires a different strategy than proving an "existence" statement. It is true that for each $x$, there exists a $y$, and you can show this existence of $y$ by providing one value (only one is required for existence), but you need to prove that for *every* $x\geq 0$, some $y$ exists so that $y^2 = x$.

We usually do this by picking an *arbitrary* $x \geq 0$. By not assigning it any particular value, we keep it arbitrary, so that what we then demonstrate about $x$ holds for every $x\geq 0$.

So we take $x \geq 0$. Then $(\sqrt x)^2 = x$, so we can put $y = \sqrt x$,  and we're done, since no matter what the $x\geq 0$, $y = \sqrt x$ is defined, and hence exists.

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by "is defined" is this similar to "exists" ?

Comment: I mention "defined" because the square root of any real number greater than or equal to is defined. And hence, the assignment of $y$ to $\sqrt x$ shows us that whatevery $x\geq 0$ might be, there exists a $y$ satisfying $y^2 = x$.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function, $$f:\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}} \to \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}} $$ $$ x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$$

Injective:  $$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y} \Rightarrow x=y$$

Surjective:  $$Dom(f)= \{x| x\geq 0\}$$ $$y \in Ran(f) \Rightarrow y \geq 0 \Rightarrow y \in Dom(f)$$ \

$\textbf{Comment}$: I left out details for you to fill in. Comment if things are still unclear. Note $y^2 \in Dom(f), \Rightarrow \exists x$ s.t $\ x = (y)^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x} = y.$